# How to reduce multiple row value for required stock [Fifo based stock out]

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I was maintaining a stock inventory system while selling a product available stock will be reduced based on oldest purchased means which product purchased first will be sold out first.
I take the sales quantity with following lines:

```
 $product_id = $request->get('product_id');
 $quantity = $request->get('quantity');
```

For that I have queried oldest available product from table with following query:

```
$stock_available = DB::table('purchase_products')
              ->select('quantity','purchase_price')
              ->where('quantity','>',0)
              ->where('product_id',$product_id[$i])
              ->orderBy('created_at','asc')
              ->get();
```

I have queried inside a for loop

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($product_id); $i++) {
  $stock_available = DB::table('purchase_products')
    ->select('quantity', 'purchase_price', 'id')
    ->where('quantity', '>', 0)
    ->where('product_id', $product_id[$i])
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
    ->get();


  foreach ($stock_available as $entry) {
    if ($quantity[$i] >= $entry->quantity) {
      $quantityFilled = $entry->quantity; // the number of items which can be filled with this entry

      DB::table('purchase_products')
        ->where('id', $entry->id)
        ->update(['quantity' => 0]);
      $quantity[$i] = $quantity[$i] - $quantityFilled; // lower the sell count by the quantity filled
    } else {
      // if $sellCount is less than the $entry->quantity, lower the quantity of entry by $sellCount and save $entry;
      $entry->quantity = $entry->quantity - $quantity[$i];
      DB::table('purchase_products')
        ->where('id', $entry->id)
        ->update(['quantity' => $entry->quantity]);
      $quantity[$i] = 0;
    }

    if ($quantity[$i] == 0) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

return redirect('sales');
```

But my problem is how can I reduced if multiple rows will be affected for required stock.
Suppose I will sell 20 items but in 1st row from query has 10, 2nd row from query has 5 and 3rd row from query has last 5 items. How do I reduce the stock?

Comment: Can you give some example dump of `$stock_available`?

Comment: 0 => {#1337 ▼
      +"quantity": "20.00"
      +"purchase_price": "750.00"
    }
    1 => {#1336 ▼
      +"quantity": "10.00"
      +"purchase_price": "800.00"
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the `$stock_available` while maintaining a `sellCount` variable to track how much to reduce by.

```php
$sellCount = 20; // 20 is based from your example above but can be set to $quantity based on question

foreach($stock_available as $entry)
{
    if($sellCount >= $entry->quantity){
        $quantityFilled = $entry->quantity; // the number of items which can be filled with this entry
        $entry->quantity = 0; // since all of the quantity will be used, remaining quantity will be 0
        $entry->save(); // save the entry
        $sellCount = $sellCount - $quantityFilled; // lower the sell count by the quantity filled
    } else {
        // if $sellCount is less than the $entry->quantity, lower the quantity of entry by $sellCount and save $entry;
        $entry->quantity = $entry->quantity - $sellCount;
        $entry->save();
        $sellCount = 0;
    }

    if ($sellCount == 0) {
        break;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I have used your code but unfortunately data not updated. I have update my question with your code. Can you please tell what's the wrong please?

Comment: What does your `$request` look like? Most likely your $stock_available is not retrieving the correct products. Please update your question with `$request` information. Does it give you any errors?

Answer (score 0):

This code first starts a database transaction to ensure that all the stock updates happen atomically. It then calculates the total available stock for the given product and throws an exception if there is not enough stock available.

```
$product_id = 123; // replace with the actual product ID
$quantity_to_decrease = 10;

DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    $available_stock = DB::table('stocks')
                        ->where('product_id', $product_id)
                        ->sum('quantity');

    if ($available_stock < $quantity_to_decrease) {
        throw new Exception("Not enough stock available.");
    }

    $stocks = DB::table('stocks')
                ->where('product_id', $product_id)
                ->orderBy('quantity', 'desc')
                ->get();

    foreach ($stocks as $stock) {
        if ($quantity_to_decrease <= 0) {
            break;
        }

        $quantity_to_reduce = min($quantity_to_decrease, $stock->quantity);

        DB::table('stocks')
            ->where('id', $stock->id)
            ->decrement('quantity', $quantity_to_reduce);

        $quantity_to_decrease -= $quantity_to_reduce;
    }

    DB::commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()], 400);
}

return response()->json(['message' => 'Stock decreased successfully.'], 200);
```